# catch and store ALL mysql database data (table rows) to use them for comparison and matching

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on a project that i have to compare all the tables between two huge databases and matching them. Actually this project aims to implement a kind of database fusion. For been more specific, if a row1 on table1.database1 describes the person "Michael" with id, phone, address, etc.. and the specific row2 on table2.database2 describes the person "Mike" with id, phone, address, etc... i have to decide after the comparison if "Michael" and "Mike" are the same persons or not.

I did the connection for both databases, I already catch up the tables, the columns and the row data. As i am not so familiar with java I don't know how to use the extracting data and start any comparison. Which is the best way to store and use them? arraylists? arrays? objects? vectors?

For example I have the following piece of code to catch the row data:

```
int j = 0;
while(resTablesData1.next()) {
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resTablesData1.getMetaData();
    int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
    System.out.println();
    for (int k=0; k<colCount ; k++) {
        String colName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        Object o = resTablesData1.getObject(colName);
        columnsArrayDB1[j][k] = o.toString();
        System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");
        System.out.print("| "+columnsArrayDB1[j][k]+" |"+"\t");
        System.out.println("|-----------------------------------------------------|");
    }
    j++;
}
```

I have the same piece of code for both databases. I have to compare the columnsArrayDB1[0][0] with columnsArrayDB2[0][0] and so on... how to do that with an optimize way?

Is it better to use an Object which would represent the data of the row? for example:

```
public class RowDataObject {
     public String col1;
     public String col2;
     // Etc
     public RowDataObject(String aCol1, String aCol2 /*.....etc */ ) {
         col1 = aCol1;
         col2 = aCol2;  //...etc
     }
}
```

and then read data

```
List<RowDataObject> allRows = new ArrayList<RowDataObject>();

ResultSet rs = //Your Query
while (rs.next())  {
     String c1 = rs.getString("A Column Name or Index");
     String c2 = rs.getString("A Column second Name or Index");
     //...etc
     allRows.add(new RowDataObject(c1,c2......));
}
```

All of my work for this project processing dynamic values as I don't know beforehand the name of schemas/tables/columns etc. Please I am kindly requested some guidelines to start with because I am confused. My main problem is how to write the appropriate classes and create objects from them using the instances to my provided code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you associating the rows between the two result sets? Are you always comparing row x from query A with row x from query B?  Or are you comparing every row from query A with every row in query B to look for matches?

Comment: Actually i catch up the data type of every column so i am able to discrete if a column is int, varchar etc. So it does not make sense to compare an int value with a string value. With this way my comparison become more flexible and reduce comparison time.

Comment: So you're comparing every int value in a row with every other int value in every other row?

Comment: Yes exactly. And every string with any other string in other row. Of course i am trying to use some "tricks" to save time consuming. For example i am trying to define which column has date values so to compare with the similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `o.toString()` to get the String value of all returned rows, you could create an object to hold each column's value, e.g.:

```
class CellValue
{
    int cellTye;
    String cellValue;

    CellValue(int cellType,String cellValue) 
    {
        this.cellType=cellType;
        this.cellValue=cellValue;
    }
}
```

Create each new object using `rsmd.getColumnType()` and `o.toString()`

Add the objects to `ArrayList` for each row, and add each row to an `ArrayList` for each data source.  you can then iterate through the two ArrayLists to compare the columns.

I haven't actually tested this, but something like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<CellValue>> cells = new ArrayList<>();

ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resTablesData1.getMetaData();
int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

while(resTablesData1.next()) {
    ArrayList<CellValue> row = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int k=0; k<colCount ; k++) {
        String colName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        Object o = resTablesData1.getObject(colName);
        row.add(new CellValue(rsmd.getColumnType(),o.toString());
    }
    cells.add(row);
}
```

When you compare the results of the two ArrayLists, you can compare `cellType` to make sure you're comparing cells of the same data type.  If you want to get fancy, you can override `.equals()` in CellValue() to compare `cellType` and `cellValue`; you can then use `cellValue1.equals(cellValue2)` to see if it's a match.